# Python - GPSD Usage on non-thread pooling

Tags: python-2.7, gps, polling, gpsd

I am implementing a GPSD polling using python:
following the python examples here:
http://www.catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html#_python_examples

There is a reason why i cant use the code in here:
https://gist.github.com/wolfg1969/4653340
Because i have to daemonize about 10 processes in my system, so i would go for the catb one for easy implementation.

I have a question on the following code why it stops after two cycles? and how could i fix this? Thanks.

```
def GpsDetection():

global gpsd
gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)

try:
    while 1:
        # Do stuff
        report = gpsd.next()
        # Check report class for 'DEVICE' messages from gpsd.  If we're expecting messages from multiple devices we should
        # inspect the message to determine which device has just become available.  But if we're just listening
        # to a single device, this may do.
        print report
        if report['class'] == 'DEVICE':
            # Clean up our current connection.
            gpsd.close()
            # Tell gpsd we're ready to receive messages.
            gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
        # Do more stuff
        print "GPSD Data is showing now!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        print datetime.datetime.now()
        print 'latitude    ' , gpsd.fix.latitude
        print 'longitude   ' , gpsd.fix.longitude
        print 'time utc    ' , gpsd.utc,' + ', gpsd.fix.time
        print 'altitude (m)' , gpsd.fix.altitude
        print 'eps         ' , gpsd.fix.eps
        print 'epx         ' , gpsd.fix.epx
        print 'epv         ' , gpsd.fix.epv
        print 'ept         ' , gpsd.fix.ept
        print 'speed (m/s) ' , gpsd.fix.speed
        print 'climb       ' , gpsd.fix.climb
        print 'track       ' , gpsd.fix.track
        print 'mode        ' , gpsd.fix.mode
        print                  
        print 'sats        ' , gpsd.satellites

        time.sleep(1)
except StopIteration:
    print "GPSD has terminated"

return
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the question I was curious how to thread JSON data from the gpsd for the low or slow gps location requirements.

If the socket the client communicates with the gpsd fills up, is not read or dumped, the gpsd closes that socket.

I'm told a lot can happen at 4800baud in one second.  It's no surprise the daemon gives up on a full buffer in about 8 to 15 seconds, or whenever it times out at.

I wrote [a threading shim for a Python 2-3 gpsd client](https://github.com/wadda/gps3/blob/master/gps3/agps3threaded.py)

That, and [the python client](https://github.com/wadda/gps3/blob/master/gps3/agps3.py), requires importing the mechanism and sleep to slow it down if nothing else will.

```
from time import sleep
from agps3threaded import AGPS3mechanism

agps_thread = AGPS3mechanism()  # Instantiate AGPS3 Mechanisms
agps_thread.stream_data(host='192.168.0.4')  # From localhost (), or other hosts, by example, (host='gps.ddns.net')
agps_thread.run_thread(usnap=.2)  # Throttle the time to sleep after an empty lookup, default 0.2 two tenths of a second

while True:  # All data is available via instantiated thread data stream attribute.
# line #140-ff of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gps3/agps.py
    print('-----')
    print(agps_thread.data_stream.time)
    print('Lat:{}'.format(agps_thread.data_stream.lat))
    print('Lon:{}'.format(agps_thread.data_stream.lon))
    print('Speed:{}'.format(agps_thread.data_stream.speed))
    print('Course:{}'.format(agps_thread.data_stream.track))
    print('-----')
    sleep(30)
```

That would solve your threaded gpsd data question.

If you want to know why the about code isn't working, where did it  break or stop, and what were the error messages?